# CakePHP, PHP, can URL Switching be detected?

Tags: php, security, session, url, cakephp

Can "behind-the-scenes" URL switching be detected? Such that when it happens, the user on the switched-to website is dropped back to its login page.

We have a production server, staging server and demo server, connecting to their respective databases. They happen to share the same physical hardware, served up by Apache, from different URLs on the hardware. We use PHP with the CakePHP framework.

What I've done a number of times is login normally to one of the websites, then enter the URL to one of the other ones, and it still works. The other website thinks I've successfully logged in, when in fact I had actually logged in to one of its "cousins". It "knows" this due to the session information that all three apparently share.

I'm sure there has to be a security risk there somewhere. I should try it with an account that is only active on one of the websites. I.e., log in successfully to one website, then see if a "cousin" accepts that account that is locally inactive due to URL-switching.

Can this be detected and prevented? If so, how? Or is this issue inconsequential?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use different session key for each server

cakephp 2.x e.g:

```
AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.ServerDev';
```

cakephp 3.x e.g:

```
'storage'=>['className' => 'Session', 'key' => 'Auth.ServerDev']
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it ought to work. I just need to figure out where in our system to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bart for pointing me in a very good direction.

The trick I found that works in CakePHP 2 is to edit the APP/Config/core.php file, find the 'Session' configuration array, and set 'cookie' to a unique name.

E.g.:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
      'cookie' => 'OUR_PRODUCTION', // or "staging", "test", "XYZ", whatever
      'defaults' => 'cake',
      'timeout' => 60,
      // other Session parameters
));
```